# validate form using parsley when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I'm using parsley validation to validate a registration form. My problem is that I have an input which will only be enabled when the user checks a check box. So how to make parsley validate that input only when the check box is checked?

```
  <form name="form1"  method="POST" data-validate="parsley">
```

How did you hear about us? :

```
      <ul class="checklist">
        <li>
          <input name="Internet" id="Internet" value="Internet"  data-mincheck="1" data-group="mygroupp" type="checkbox">
          <label>Internet</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="Newspaper" id="Newspaper" value="Newspaper" type="checkbox" data-mincheck="1" data-group="mygroupp">
          <label>Newspaper</label>
        </li> <li>
          <input name="Others" id="Others" class="input_control" value="Others" type="checkbox"/ data-mincheck="1" data-group="mygroupp" onClick="enable_text(this.checked)">
          <label>Others, Please Specify:</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="Otherinput" id="Otherinput" class="quter-width align-right margin_top_5"  data-required="true"  disabled="disabled" >
      </p>
```

The validation for the checkboxs is working fine but I want to add validation for "otherinput" input field which will only be validated when the "Others" checkbox is checked 
Can anyone direct me please. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to demonstrate effort 1st. It's like the streetside beggar in a way, your sign just says "GIMME" . you need something more flashy - at least "God bless… Gimve help please"

Comment: Post your code, what you have tried till now. This will also help you in learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Parsley.js provides this functionality out of the box. Instead, you can write it custom by registering an onchange event listener like so:

```
$('input#others').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#otherinput').attr('disabled', 'false');
  } else {
    $('#otherinput').attr('disabled', 'true');
  }
});
```

Note: this assumes lowercase ID names (i.e. 'otherinput' instead of 'Otherinput').

I haven't tested, but something like this should work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

Parsley rely on jQuery (>= 1.6) that would need to be called before including Parsley.

Then, you can either use parsley.js unminified file or parsley.min.js minified one. These files and other builds (Remote, Extras..) are available here.

Finally, add data-parsley-validate to each  you want to be validated.

That would look pretty much like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>

<form data-parsley-validate>
...
</form>
```

It has isValid() method that returns you true if validations is/are met successfully, so you can check whether form has valid data or not.